# How to install newm on Ubuntu?

Tags: wayland

I'm thinking about using [newm](https://github.com/jbuchermn/newm) on my laptop and I was wondering if it worked on Ubuntu. It only has tutorials for Arch and NixOS installs.

Comment: I opened a github issue https://github.com/jbuchermn/newm/issues/137 Let's wait for the developers to address it

Comment: It would require porting so no there will be no method of installing it on Ubuntu. paperwm is a gnome shell extension attempting something similar.